Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107) with `tokio::io::copy_bidirectional`
I'm trying to proxy a TCP connection using tokio.
I have the following:
let std_stream: std::net::TcpStream = socket.into();
std_stream.set_nonblocking(true)?;
let mut inbound = TcpStream::from_std(std_stream)?;
debug!("created inbound tcp stream from socket");

tokio::spawn(async move {
    match TcpStream::connect(&dest_addr).await {
        Ok(mut outbound) => {
            debug!("connected to {dest_addr}");

            match tokio::io::copy_bidirectional(&mut inbound, &mut outbound).await {
                Ok((nsent, nrcvd)) => {
                    debug!(sent_bytes = nsent, rcvd_bytes = nrcvd, "bytes copied");
                    return Ok(());
                }

                Err(err) => {
                    error!(
                        "️ — proxying for address {} failed: {}",
                        &dest_addr, err
                    );
                    return Err(err);
                }
            }
        }
        Err(err) => {
            error!(
                "unable to connect to downstream host {:?}: {err}",
                dest_addr
            );

            return Err(err);
        }
    }
});

I'm turning a socket2::Socket into a tokio::net::TcpStream to then use tokio::io::copy_bidirectional to proxy the connection. I need the inbound socket2::Socket, I can't just use a tokio::net::TcpStream for that. In general this seems to work. I can use curl to make an HTTPS request and the tls handshake happens and I get a response. However, I see the following logs:
{"timestamp":"2024-04-15T17:33:56.042465Z","level":"DEBUG","fields":{"message":"created inbound tcp stream from socket"},"target":"tfw"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-15T17:33:56.080270Z","level":"DEBUG","fields":{"message":"connected to 104.244.42.129:443"},"target":"tfw"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-15T17:33:56.342300Z","level":"ERROR","fields":{"message":"️ — proxying for address 104.244.42.129:443 failed: Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107)"},"target":"tfw"}

I would expect to see the "bytes copied" log but I don't. Am I doing something wrong here? Everything I've checked for Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107) has been things like people sending data on the wrong socket, but I don't see that happening here.
Update 4/16/24 at 10:00 AM:
I implemented my own version of copy_bidirectional (where I took it from can be found here:
/// Runs the actual proxying of a socket.
async fn transfer(mut incoming: TcpStream, mut outbound: TcpStream) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    // Split the streams into read and write halves.
    let (mut read_inbound, mut write_inbound) = incoming.split();
    let (mut read_outbound, mut write_outbound) = outbound.split();

    // Connect the client reader to the server writer.
    // That is, whenever we receive data from the client, we forward it to the server.
    let client_to_server = async {
        tokio::io::copy(&mut read_inbound, &mut write_outbound)
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| {
                error!(
                    error = e.to_string(),
                    "error copying read_inbound to write_outbound!"
                )
            })?;

        debug!("finished copying read_inbound to write_outbound, shutting down write_outbound");
        write_outbound
            .shutdown()
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| error!(error = e.to_string(), "error shutting down write_outbound!"))
    };

    // Connect the server reader to the client writer.
    // That is, whenever we receive data from the server, we forward it to the client.
    let server_to_client = async {
        tokio::io::copy(&mut read_outbound, &mut write_inbound)
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| {
                error!(
                    error = e.to_string(),
                    "error copying read_outbound to write_inbound!"
                )
            })?;

        debug!("finished copying read_outbound to write_inbound, shutting down write_inbound");
        write_inbound
            .shutdown()
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| error!(error = e.to_string(), "error shutting down write_inbound!"))
    };

    // Poll both tasks.
    tokio::try_join!(client_to_server, server_to_client)?;

    Ok(())
}

This reproduces the error, but I see in the logs that the error I'm getting happens after everything has been copied, when write_inbound is being closed. I don't get an error when closing write_outbound. I'm going to keep playing with this to see what's going on but I suspect that curl is closing the connection, which closes the inbound stream, so that by the time I'm closing it myself it's already closed, hence the error.
Update 4/16/24 at 10:20 AM:
I removed the close of write_outbound, just to see if somehow closing one TcpStream was closing the other. The error still happened when closing write_inbound, which to me confirms that the client closed that connection so by the time I go close it I get the error.

What happens if you write a small script to send some TCP data, and then close the socket gracefully? It might be that in your example curl is shutting down the socket in some way that causes the underlying transport to fail. The docs for copy_bidirectional say that it will return an error unless the other end uses proper shutdown.

I don't think doing that would be useful because curl is a valid use-case for what I'm doing, and I doubt it has a bug. I need to conform myself to what clients like curl are going to do. I implemented my own version of copy_bidirectional that I'm using to play around with what's happening and I'm going to update my answer on what I'm finding as I go along.

I was able to figure out what was going on. Basically, when curl exits, it closes the connection before the server closes the connection, so by the time the server gets around to doing it, it can't so it returns ErrorKind::NotConnected.
I changed my implementation of transfer to this:
/// Runs the actual proxying of a socket.
async fn transfer(mut incoming: TcpStream, mut outbound: TcpStream) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    // Split the streams into read and write halves.
    let (mut read_inbound, mut write_inbound) = incoming.split();
    let (mut read_outbound, mut write_outbound) = outbound.split();

    // Connect the client reader to the server writer.
    // That is, whenever we receive data from the client, we forward it to the server.
    let client_to_server = async {
        tokio::io::copy(&mut read_inbound, &mut write_outbound)
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| {
                error!(
                    error = e.to_string(),
                    "error copying read_inbound to write_outbound"
                )
            })?;

        debug!("finished copying read_inbound to write_outbound, shutting down write_outbound");
        write_outbound
            .shutdown()
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| error!(error = e.to_string(), "error shutting down write_outbound!"))
    };

    // Connect the server reader to the client writer.
    // That is, whenever we receive data from the server, we forward it to the client.
    let server_to_client = async {
        tokio::io::copy(&mut read_outbound, &mut write_inbound)
            .await
            .inspect_err(|e| {
                error!(
                    error = e.to_string(),
                    "error copying read_outbound to write_inbound!"
                )
            })?;

        debug!("finished copying read_outbound to write_inbound, shutting down write_inbound");
        if let Err(err) = write_inbound.shutdown().await {
            match err.kind() {
                // The client can shut down the inbound connection sometimes. If this is the case, shutting down this connection
                // will throw this error. In practice, it doesn't really matter. There's no good way to check if a connection is
                // closed without trying to read from it and seeing what happens. It's effectively the same as doing this.
                ErrorKind::NotConnected => {
                    debug!("unable to shut down inbound write stream because the client already shut it down, nothing to see here");
                }

                _ => {
                    error!(
                        error = err.to_string(),
                        error_kind = err.kind().to_string(),
                        "error shutting down write_inbound!"
                    );

                    return Err(err);
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    };

    // Poll both tasks.
    tokio::try_join!(client_to_server, server_to_client)?;

    Ok(())
}

